# How to query and apply filter on a field that has multi_field type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am going through the documentation and understood that multi_field is used to apply different analyzers on one field.

```
{
"tweet" : {
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {
            "type" : "multi_field",
            "fields" : {
                "name" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed"},
                "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have indexed the data as follows

```
/tweet/1   { 
  "name" : "anil"
}
```

And I am searching for the same as follows.

```
/<indexname>/_search
```

I am getting the data as follows.

```
hits : [
{
           "_index" : ...
           ....
           "_source" : {
                  "name" : "anil" 
          }
 }
]
```

So far this is good.

Now I am looking for match.

```
GET <indexname>/_search
   {
          "query": {
              "match": {
                 "name": "anil"
              }
           }
    }
```

The above one works fine since I have the analyzer applied on it.

My question is, If I want to apply filter with exact string, I am getting 0 hits.

```
GET <indexname>/_search
        {
           "query": {
                   "filtered": {
                         "query": {
                              "match_all": {}
                          },
                          "filter": {
                                  "term": {
                                        "name" : "anil"
                                    }
                          }
                   }
               }
         }
```

Please suggest what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
GET <indexname>/_search
    {
       "query": {
               "filtered": {
                     "query": {
                          "match_all": {}
                      },
                      "filter": {
                              "term": {
                                    "name.untouched" : "anil"
                                }
                      }
               }
           }
     }
```

Also, you don't have to use multi_fields anymore, you can just use fields, as explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html?q=multi_fiel), but I don't think that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes, the above one works.
My requirement was I need to apply 2 analyzers on one field. so that I had to go with that approach.When used it, I was in assumption that if I same name, it will look for both.
Seems like it is not, we have to handle it in my API code that If I want exact match look for "name.untouched" if you want to search on analyzer use name.